# Problem with large rails background process not completing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, redis, background-process, sidekiq

I have a rails background process (using Sidekiq and Redis) that parses XML files and later makes modifications to it.

The background process works as intended but stays in processing and does not complete when the XML is really big. My two assumptions for this are:

1. My background process is storing large amounts of text from the XML into arrays `old_texts` & `new_texts` and it is causing issues
2. My background process is timing out

The problem occurs on both my development machine (& staging).

I'm not sure how to debug this problem. I don't think posting my code will help but I'll do it in case you need an idea of what I'm doing:

```
old_texts, new_texts = [], []

xml_no_includs = ["pctHeight","pctWidth","posOffset","delText","delInstrText","instrText"]    

search = '//w:document//w:body//w:p'

ancestors_excluds = ['//mc:Fallback', '//w:tbl', '//wps:txbx', '//v:textbox']

old_texts, new_texts = get_texts(old_texts, new_texts, XML, xml_no_includs, ancestors_excluds, search)

search_param = '//w:document//w:body//w:p'

ancestors_excluds = ['//mc:Fallback', '//w:tbl', '//wps:txbx', '//v:textbox']

replace_texts(old_texts, new_texts, XML, search_param, ancestors_excluds)
```

-

```
def replace_texts(old_texts, new_texts, XML, search_param, ancestors_excluds)
  text_params = './/text()[not(ancestor::wp14:pctHeight or ancestor::wp14:pctWidth or ancestor::wp:posOffset or ancestor::w:instrText or ancestor::w:delText or ancestor::w:delInstrText)]'
  inc = 0

  old_texts.each_with_index do |old_text, index|
    accum_string = ''
    double_break = false
    XML.search(search_param).drop(inc).each do |line|
      inc += 1
      temp = true
        line.search(text_params).each do |p|
          temp2 = true
          ancestors_excluds.each do |param|
            temp2 = false if p.ancestors(param).present? 
          end
          if temp2 == true
            if accum_string.blank? && !p.content.blank?
              accum_string += p.content
              p.content = new_texts[index]
            else
              accum_string += p.content unless accum_string.blank?
              p.content = ''
            end
            if accum_string.strip == old_text.strip            
              double_break = true
              break
            end
          end
        end    
      break if double_break == true
    end
  end
end
```

-

```
def get_texts(old_texts, new_texts, XML, xml_no_includs, ancestors_excluds, search_param)
  XML.xpath(search_param).each do |p|
    text = ''
    temp = true
    p.search('text()').each do |p2|
      temp2 = true
      temp2 = false if xml_no_includs.include?(p2.parent.name)
      ancestors_excluds.each do |param|
        temp2 = false if p2.ancestors(param).present? 
      end
      text += p2.text if temp2 == true
    end
    unless text.blank?
      old_texts.append(text) 
      new_texts.append(text.gsub(/(.)./, '\1*') )
    end
  end
  old_texts.reject!(&:blank?)
  new_texts.reject!(&:blank?)

  return old_texts, new_texts
end
```

Comment: sidekick doesn't have a timeout as I know. maybe Linux OOM killer kills the process. check the system logs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up refactoring my code to manage each element that was originally going to be pushed into the array. Didn't speed it up more, but at least the background task completes after a few hours.